# Why is JS not recognizing the json variable in nested json

Tags: javascript, json

I was working on setting dynamic profile cards for html in js and using an external json file and i keep running into a problem where the socials part of the js json script displays the values as undefined

```
<script>var profiles = {} 
window.onload = function () { 
    GetProfiles() 
}
function GetProfiles(){
    $.getJSON('https://gameremporium.us/image/Profile/profile.json', function(data) {

        var projson = data;
        for(var q in projson){
            jsonpro = projson[q];
            for(var i in jsonpro){
                profile = jsonpro[i];
                if (typeof profile["name"] != "" || typeof profile["name"] != undefined){
                    profiles["name"] += profile.name;
                }
                if (typeof profile["Nick_name"] != "" || typeof profile["Nick_name"] != undefined){
                    profiles["Nick"] += profile.Nick_name;
                    }
                if (typeof profile["role"] != "" || typeof profile["role"] != undefined){
                    profiles["role"] += profile.role;
                    }
                if (typeof profile["description"] != "" || typeof profile["description"] != undefined){
                    profiles["description"] += profile.description;
                    }
                if (typeof profile["image"] != "" || typeof profile["image"] != undefined){
                    profiles["image"] += profile.image_name;
                    }
                if (typeof profile["imageBG"] != "" || typeof profile["imageBG"] != undefined){
                    profiles["imageBG"] += profile.imageBG_name;
                    }
                if (typeof profile["contact"] != "" || typeof profile["contact"] != undefined){
                    profiles["contact"] += profile.contact_link;
                    }
                for(var a in profile){
                    social = profile[a].social_links;
                        for(var a in social){
                            media = social[a]
                    
                            if(media["link_one"].name && media["link_one"].link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_one"]["name"] += media.name;
                                profiles.social["link_one"]["link"] += media.link;
                            }
                            if(media.name && media.link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_two"]["name"]  += media.name
                                profiles.social["link_two"]["link"]  += media.link
                            }
                            if(media.name && media.link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_three"]["name"]  += media.name
                                profiles.social["link_three"]["link"]  += media.link
                            }
                            if(media.name && media.link_four.link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_four"]["name"]  += media.name
                                profiles.social["link_four"]["link"]  += media.link
                            }
                            if(media.name && media.link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_five"]["name"]  += media.name
                                profiles.social["link_five"]["link"]  += media.link
                            }
                            if(media.name && media.link != ""){
                                profiles.social["link_six"]["name"] += media.name
                                profiles.social["link_six"]["link"] += media.link
                            }
                        }
                }
                SetProfiles(profiles); 
            }
        };
    })
    };

function SetProfiles(profiles){
    for(var i in profiles){
        profile = profiles[i];
        document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML = '<div class="card"><img src="'+profile["imageBG"]+'" alt="background-image" class="bg-img"><img src='+profile["image"]+'" alt="avatar" class="profile-img"><h1>"'+profile["name"]+'"</h1><p class="about-info">"'+profile["description"]+'"</p><a href="'+profile["contact"]+'" class="btn">Contact</a><ul class="social-list" id="social"><li><a href="@" class="social-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li></ul></div>';
    }
}</script>
THe problem
```

code is below and is not getting the name value from the socials nested value in the profiles part of the json file

```
for(var a in profile){
                    social += profile[a].social_links;

                    if(typeof social.link_one.name && social.social_links.link_one.link != ""){
```

EDIT: Updated the code now just displays everything back to the underfined

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) will **never** return an empty string. Are you sure that's what you're meant to be checking

Comment: `social.link_one` is undefined, possibly because the prior `+=` line produces a string and strings don’t have `link_one` attributes.

Comment: You check if `social.social_links` exists but then operate on `profiles.social_links`

Comment: i noticed that i fxed that and still get it

Comment: i have updated the code and all values are undefined

Comment: Guy Incognito still laughing inside for doing that

Comment: Have you fixed the problem with `+=`? `undefined + 'Some string'` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's too much to fix in your example code so instead of going over it line by line I'll just provide this alternative code suggestion.

```js
// kicks off the profile fetching/rendering
makeCards();


// gets the data and invokes addCard for each profile
async function makeCards () {
  const json = await getProfiles();
  const container = document.getElementById('profiles');
  Object.values(json.Profiles).forEach(profile => addCard(profile, container));
}

// makes an individual profile card and adds to parent
function addCard(profile, parent) {
  // bail if we don't have a profile or a parent node
  if (!profile || !parent) {
    return;
  }
  
  // use a template literal instead of string concatenation for the html
  parent.innerHTML += `
  <div class="card">
    ${imgHtml(profile)}
    <h1>${profile.name}</h1>
    <p class="about-info">
      ${contactLinkHtml(profile)}
      <ul class="social-list" id="social">
        <li>
          <a href="@" class="social-link><i class="fa facebook-square"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
  `
}

// use fallback image when image_name isn't present
function imgHtml ({image_name}) {
  return `<img src="${image_name || '//placekitten.com/200'}" alt="avatar" class="profile-img" />`
}

// return html only when contact_link is present
function contactLinkHtml ({contact_link}) {
  return !contact_link ? '' : `<a href="${contact_link}" class="btn">Contact</a>`
}


// ------ the rest is just hand-waving data stuff --------- //


// simulate the fetch request
async function getProfiles() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve(json(), 500));
  })
}

// sample data
function json() {
  return {
    "Profiles": {
      "profile 1": {
        "name": "LoneOxi",
        "Nick_name": "",
        "image_name": "",
        "imageBG_name": "",
        "contact_link": "",
        "description": "",
        "role": "",
        "social_links": {
          "link_one": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_two": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_three": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_four": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_five": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_six": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_seven": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "profile 2": {
        "name": "Lonnie Gibson",
        "Nick_name": "Quentin",
        "image_name": "//placekitten.com/201",
        "imageBG_name": "LonnieGBG.jpg",
        "contact_link": "",
        "description": "",
        "role": "",
        "social_links": {
          "link_one": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_two": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_three": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_four": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_five": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_six": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          },
          "link_seven": {
            "name": "",
            "link": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#profiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #00000033;
  width: 200px;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.profile-img {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="profiles"></div>
```

Update:

I'd strongly recommend you use arrays for lists of items instead of naming each one, e.g. `profile 1`, `profile 2`.

Your list of profiles could look like this for example. (I've omitted some of the profile properties in the interest of brevity and readability.)

```json
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "LoneOxi",
      "nickname": "",
      "imageUrl": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "Lonnie Gibson",
      "nickname": "Quentin",
      "imageUrl": "//placekitten.com/201"
    }
  ]
}
```

In addition to eliminating noise and complexity in the json, you can use the array iteration methods like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), etc. directly.

```js
obj.Profiles.forEach(profile => console.log(profile.name))
```

Same for `link_one`, `link_two`. There's no point in naming them this way. I'd recommend you either use the name as the key:

```json
{
  "social_links": {
    "facebook": "https://...",
    "twitter": "https://...",
    "instagram": "https://...."
  }
}
```

You could iterate these using a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), or via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
for(const name in social_links) {
  const url = social_links[name];
  // do stuff with name and url
}

Object.entries(social_links).forEach(([name, url]) => {
  // do stuff with name and url
});
```

Or just use an array of the objects you're already using:

```json
{
  "social_links": [
    {
      "name": "facebook",
      "link": "https://..."
    },
    {
      "name": "twitter",
      "link": "https://..."
    },
    {
      "name": "instagram",
      "link": "https://..."
    },
  ]
}
```

```js
social_links.forEach(item => {
  // do stuff with item.name, item.link
})
```

I think it's a good idea to keep the root of the json response as an object to allow for additional metadata or whatever, but taken together your API response might look something more like this.

```js
{
  metadata: {
    lastUpdated: '2023-04-04'
  },
  profiles: [
    {
      name: "Lonnie Gibson",
      image: "/path/to/avatar.jpg",
      bgImage: "/path/to/bgImage.jpg",
      social: [
        {
          name: 'facebook',
          url: 'https://facebook.com/...'
        },
        {
          name: 'twitter',
          url: 'https://twitter.com/...'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Someone Else",
      image: "/path/to/avatar.jpg",
      bgImage: "/path/to/bgImage.jpg",
      social: [
        {
          name: 'facebook',
          url: 'https://facebook.com/...'
        },
        {
          name: 'twitter',
          url: 'https://twitter.com/...'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: so asuming with the await there, was my original code executing before the json was opened?

Comment: No. I just didn’t need (or want) jQuery and I prefer promises over callbacks. You could leave your data fetch the way you have it if you prefer.

Comment: ok i understand that my code was a rough code i put together in a few minutes i am coming back to js what kind of functions is that that calls the json?

Comment: i figured out how it works

Comment: If you control the json shape I'd strongly recommend you use arrays instead of "profile 1", "profile 2", and "link_one", "link_two", etc.

Comment: oh ok i just always found it easier to work with json objects but will learn more into arrays and also i am learning this way in js is there a resource where i can have a more detailed explaination of how this exactly works?

Comment: in the code above how would i write it to get each social link i replaced the <li> tags with `${socialLinkHtml(profile.social_links)}` and added the function function `socialLinkhtml ({name}, {link}) {
     return !name ? '' : <a href="${link}" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-#{name}"> 
   </i>${name}</a>
   }` but pretty sure not done correctly as this is actually my first time with doing it this way

Comment: Updated my answer with suggestions on improving the shape of your json response.

Comment: thanks you for helping on this and i see what u mean by the arrays also

Comment: I have set the social links as the array as you have suggested and having a little trouble trying to get the foreach to work  i have the following code am i missing something and for the sake of the code in here i do have the tilde before and after the <li> tags  `function socialLinkHtml ({social}){
 social.forEach(item => {
  return !name ? '' && !url ? '' : <li>
          <a href="${url}" class="social-link><i class="fa #{name}-square"></i></a>
        </li>
 })
}`

Comment: i updated my code and is function `socialLinkHtml ({social}){
 social.forEach(item => {
  return <li>
          <a href="${item.url}" class="social-link><i class="fa #{item.name}-square"></i></a>
        </li>
 })
}`

Comment: it outputs undefined

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything, and for this you should use `map` instead of `forEach`.